# How to force matplotlib to show values on x-axis as integers

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Code like this:

```
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='x', useOffset=False)
plt.plot(range(1, 3), logger.acc)
plt.xlabel("Epochs")
plt.ylabel("Accuracy")
plt.show()
```

Produces a result like this:
[image: plot]

I want the x axis to only have whole integer numbers. There should be a simple flag for this, but i can't find it.

Answer (score 30):

Just use the following where you set the `xticks` as the integer values generated by the `range()` function. You can replace the numbers with whatever range you are plotting within

```
plt.xticks(range(1,3))
```

Answer (score 20):

You may use a `MultipleLocator` with the base set to `1`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

class logger():
    acc = [ .26, .36]

plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='x', useOffset=False)
plt.plot(range(1, 3), logger.acc)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MultipleLocator(1))
plt.xlabel("Epochs")
plt.ylabel("Accuracy")
plt.show()
```

[image]